# Why can't I ping my PS3 Using a wired connection?

Tags: ping, ps3, ps3-media-server

- PS3 is using the inbuilt wireless network adapter (I cannot change this)

When I try to ping the PS3 from ANY computer which is on a wired ethernet connection, I get Request Timed Out errors.

Whenever I ping from a computer with a wireless connection, it works just fine.

To be clear:

- Pinging from Wireless PC to Wireless PS3 works
- Pinging from Wired PC to Wireless PS3 fails

I have tried this on several PC's and Laptops all with the same results. As an attempted solution I have set up static IP's on all related devices.

More information:

- Default Gateway = 192.168.2.1
- PS3(wireless) = 192.168.2.100
- PC(wired)  = 192.168.2.99
- Subnet Mask(for both devices, I have made sure) = 255.255.255.0

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping e.g. your laptop (when connected via wireless interface) from your desktop (connected via wired interface)?

Comment: Pretty sure the problem hides in your AP.. What is your AP model and it's configuration?

Comment: Try using MTR (WinMTR) or traceroute to determine where your requests are going.  Can you ping the gateway from each wired system?

Comment: - @icyrock Yep
- @Andrejs It's a Belkin 5D8231-4 v3000. What regarding its configuration would you like to know specifically? DHCP enabled, UpnP enabled
- @Everett It times out at first hop. Yep, I can ping the gateway from all systems including wired

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but when you use a wired connection, you are connecting to the same router that your PS3 is wirelessly connected to, right? If so, does your router settings allow you to see connected clients? You can check to make sure all clients are registered and getting IPs properly.

Comment: Can you check If the "Client isolation" feature is turned on? See if it helps.

Comment: you're not using `ping -l 65000`, right ;)

Comment: I agree with Andrejs's idea.  I guess one thing I'd look for is not only whether the PC can ping the PS3, but whether it even even ARP for it.  Some wireless routers keep wireless clients completely separate from wired clients.  From the PC, try to ping the PS3 and then immediately issue an "arp -a" (Windows) to make sure you are showing the PS3's IP associated with a MAC address.  If not, the AP is preventing the PC from communicating with the PS3 in its current configuration.

Comment: You are disabling the wireless when you connect the wired connection as well?  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Is NAT turned on in your wireless router.  If you wish to access wireless devices from your wired network you will need NAT turned off.

Do you have your wireless router connected to the wired network through the internet port or through a switch port?  If it is through the internet port it will need a different subnet.

Comment: Actually, if you want to access a wireless device that is behind the router, from a wired device that is also behind the router...  NAT is irrelevant.  As long as both devices are behind the router, you'll be able to reach them.  For example, I can reach everything that is behind my router, wireless or wired...

Comment: What Benjamin says is true, however you need to be aware that anybody that can access your wireless network can then also access your wired network.  It is better to keep wired side of network separate from wireless side through the use of VLans or just subnet separation with a router that can restrict what flows where.

Answer (score 1):

This may simply be an issue with wireless segregation. What type of wireless router are you using, and are the wired ports on the same router? I have seen in past on a couple of routers that there will be a setting that will allow or deny the wireless attached devices to communicate with each other.

As mentioned earlier, without the make and model of your router(s) we can't fully assist.

Answer (score 1):

I second the wireless separation suggested by @iambryan above. Most consumer routers today have an option to not bridge the wireless interface to the same switch plane that the wired ports are on. The is a security feature to keep wireless intruders from being able to take over the entire network.

Answer (score 0):

Does pinging from wired pc to wireless laptop work?

If not the problem is you are on two different routers. Happens all the time, you may be connecting to your neighbors wireless and not realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a segmentation issue.  I'd switch back to DHCP to confirm that all devices are getting IP leases from the router in the same subnet.  Both wireless and wired devices should be getting 192.168.2.x addresses from the pool specified in the router.  If something isn't, you probably have a wiring problem (wrong ports) or additional HW getting in the way (two dhcp servers, etc).

Another possibility (though remote) is that some routers will issue a WAN IP directly to a LAN machine when it's designated as a DMZ device.  Again, this can be confirmed by switching everything back to DHCP and checking what IP's everything gets.